# How to determine the size of a http response header?

Tags: apache, http-headers, size, google-chrome-devtools

I want to determine the size of the response header. I assume I could do so by subtracting the size of the response body from the combined size derived using Chrome DevTools.

From [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network#network_panel_overview):

> **Size** is the combined size of the response headers (usually a few
>   hundred bytes) plus the response body, as *delivered by the server*.

The uncompressed size of a .js file is 375 bytes, given by the `Content`. The combined `size` given by DevTools is 701 bytes.

In addition, I have the following information from [Apache access log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) to record the transfer of the same .js file:

```
%b = 273 bytes (Size of response in bytes, excluding HTTP headers)
%O = 842 bytes (Bytes sent, including headers, cannot be zero)
```

Should I use `%0 - %b`, `%0 - Content`, `Size - %b` or `Size - Content`? In addition, can anyone tell me why there is a difference between `%0` and `Size`?

Answer (score 22):

I dont know what tool you need, but its easy to count in shell using curl utility, assuming you have following header:

```
root@sup ~# curl -I  http://domain.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.1
Date: Thu, 05 Dec 2013 19:40:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 199
Last-Modified: Sun, 15 Sep 2013 17:06:37 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

to count it:

```
root@sup ~# curl -s -w \%{size_header} -o /dev/null http://domain.com 
215
```

result: 215 bytes.

Comment: It returns 0 for the above js file. Seems it doesn't work on https though it returns a value of 261 on http. In any case, the size of a http response header served from curl will not be the same as that served from apache server to users on the internet.

Comment: for https curl have -k key:  
`root@sup ~# curl -sk -w \%{size_header} -o /dev/null  https://dom.net`
    201

Comment: Thanks, it returns 261 on https now. But still, you have not answered my two questions in the last paragraph of my original post.

Comment: Actually I am not aware of chrome devtools,  but I believe `%0 - %b` - is what you need, you can compare that result with curl command output that I gave above for sure.

Comment: If you have Chrome browser installed, it is available at `Tools` -> `Web Developer` -> `Network`. By the way `%0 - %b` gives me 569 (842-273), which is different from what curl gives me (261). Can you explain why you think it is `%0 - %b`?

Comment: oh sorry, i got you wrong. So i just tested it:
in Dev tools:
Size - shows the summ of header+conent
Content - shows the size of content only, 

the same could be seen via curl:
`# curl -s -w \%{size_header}:\%{size_download} -o /dev/null http://dom.com
193:943`

As for differences of size in Apache logs, - looks like it appends additional info to header, to see that you should use `tcpdump` utility on server size to capture that request packets and see the real size.

Comment: I am sorry, but the response header size obtained from curl (261) does not match any of the following `%0 - %b` (569), `%0 - Content` (467), `Size - %b` (428) or `Size - Content` (326). The size_download is 375, but it doesn't confirm anything about header size. Do note that the file is in compressed format.

Comment: on my site it doesn't have such difference, can you give a link to a page you are testing with?

Comment: Sorry, I can't. The page is not hosted online.

Comment: You can get different response headers depending on the client, i.e. the browser can request capabilities (gzip compression, keep-alives, etc.) that affect the headers in the response, so you cannot assume testing with browser and curl will give you the exact same headers from the server.

Answer (score 0):

The **%O** logging in Apache includes any SSL overhead, so you actually have SSL-bytes + header_bytes + compressed_content in that figure, while Chrome's *Size* seems to only have header_bytes + compressed_content. And to make it hard, Chrome's *Content* is the size of the *uncompressed content*.

Based on your figures I say on the network you have 261 bytes of headers + 273 bytes of compressed content + 308 bytes of SSL bytes, and Chrome by only telling you the uncompressed size of the content makes it impossible to determine the size of the headers from only the figures available in Chrome.

Comment: If what you said is right, then Chrome's size should be `261 (header) + 273 (compressed content) = 534`. But it is `701`.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the information that Chrome's Content was 701 (too many numbers in too many different combinations in multiple places - I lost track of them all). I cannot explain exactly how Chrome counts the stuff, but from my own experiments I can clearly see that when using HTTP compression the *Size* can be significantly smaller than *Content*, so you simply cannot subtract these two values or you will get an error depending on how much the content has been compressed.

Comment: Based on these discussions we can rule out `%O` (includes SSL data) and Chrome's `Content` (uncompressed). From the given variables I think the closest result should be `Size - %b`, although the result (428) in your case seems a bit large. You could verify this by copy-pasting the response header source seen in Chrome's DevTools to a file and see how large a file you get.